# Laravel logout button get warning message

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, laravel

I want to implement that anywhere on the site, when user is clicking on `Logout` button, to get a `javascript confirm box`.

Laravel logout button is looking like :

```
       <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{route('logout')}}" onclick="event.preventDefault();document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
            <span class="text-danger">
                <i class="fa fa-fw fa-sign-out"></i>Logout
            </span>
         </a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use javascript `confirm()` function.

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="{{route('logout')}}" onclick="return logout(event);">
     <span class="text-danger">
        <i class="fa fa-fw fa-sign-out"></i>Logout
     </span>
</a> 

<script type="text/javascript">
    function logout(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            var check = confirm("Do you really want to logout?");
            if(check){ 
               document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();
            }
     }
</script>
```

**OR**

```
     <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{route('logout')}}" onclick="event.preventDefault();var check = confirm("Do you really want to logout?");if(check){document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();}">
        <span class="text-danger">
            <i class="fa fa-fw fa-sign-out"></i>Logout
        </span>
     </a>
```